# Have I referenced my website's SSL certificate chain correctly?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, openssl

The SSL certificate chain for one of my websites is incomplete, and I learned that I should reference the intermediate certificate in the virtual hosts file.

Comodo sent me two intermediate certificates with the main PositiveSSL one, COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt and COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt. They are both in the format

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
somegibberish
somegibberish
somegibberish
somegibberish
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

So they looked ready to reference. When I bought the SSL for my website back in December I uploaded both of these intermediates as well as the main PositiveSSL certificate to the same folder. I added the lines `SSLCertificateChainFile...` below.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
...
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/domain.com/domain.com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/domain.com/domain.com.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/domain.com/COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/domain.com/COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt
```

I then ran `service apache2 reload` in the command shell afterwards with no issues.

Did I do this right?

**Update:** I looked at [this page](http://www.bensprotips.com/2014/04/apache-sslcertificatechainfile-directive-deprecated-sslcertificatefile/), which says that `SSLCertificateChainFile` is deprecated, and that I should put all the certificates all the main certificate file in a certain order. I tried that, reloaded apache2, and there are still no apparent issues so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the correct configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
...
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/domain.com/domain.com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/domain.com/domain.com.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/domain.com/COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt
```

In `COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt` I copied and pasted the contents of `COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt` at the bottom.

After reloading Apache and running the site through an [SSL checker](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html) the chain was reported as being valid.

Comment: Yeah I clicked it earlier but it said I needed to wait two days.